# Will this LM317 Circuit work for my application?

Tags: voltage-regulator, circuit-design, design, lm317

I am attempting to design a circuit to charge lithium 18650 batteries is a 3S configuration. I understand that a BMS is recommended, but I am not concerned with that. I have built this LM317 circuit (pictured below) and seem to be having some trouble.

When I connect a multi-meter to the outputs with no load attached, I get a full range from 1.27 V up to 18.06 V when I adjust the potentiometer, just as I had intended. But the problems start when I connect a small load to it (12 V, 0.15 A computer fan). Once the fan is attached, I can't get more than 11.5 V on the multimeter. I can adjust the fan speed just fine from 1.27 V to 11.5 V, but once it's at 11.5 V, continuing to rotate the potentiometer does not increase speed or raise voltage level.

So overall I am just concerned that once I connect my battery as a load, it will not charge it to a full 12.6 V as needed.

So my questions are:

- Is there a reason I cannot adjust fan speed beyond 11.5 V?
- Is there a flaw in my design?
- If I set it to 12.6 V while unloaded, and then attach the battery pack, will it fully charge it?
- Is there an easy modification I could make to my design to make it work properly?

Here is what I have already tried in order to fix the issues I'm having:

- Originally I had R2 at 220 ohms, but increasing to 840 ohms gave about 0.25 V more on the fan test.
- I have tried removing D1 to avoid voltage drop, but that only increased Vout by 0.1 V

Note: I have no formal education with electronics nor am I very experienced. I am simply an at hobbyist who finds this interesting and fun and am trying to learn more.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Debugging ideas: 1) increase the input voltage higher than 19V or bypass D1 so the input voltage is higher. 2) Measure voltage at all three terminals of your regulator when the fan is connected... if ADJ is 1.25, then the regulator THINKS it is doing its job. If OUT is at the desired voltage, then the regulator IS doing its job. Maybe you are losing too much voltage across R3. What is the voltage across R3?

Comment: PS, don't reply to my comment with a comment. Edit your question to include any new information. You don't need to say "EDIT"  or anything. Just work the new info in anywhere.

Comment: What is the source of that 19vdc? Please describe it in detail. If it some old electric power tool battery its output voltage may drop significantly when you put any load on it.

Comment: If you do manage to adjust the output to 12.6 V and connect your 3S LiPo, eventually they will be destroyed, this is not how you charge LiPos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @mkeith's comment to monitor the voltage (relative to ground) at the LM317's power input pin when the fan is attached to the LM317's output pin, and the fan is running. If at all possible use an oscilloscope, not a multimeter, to perform this voltage measurement.  *(NB: If you don't have an oscilloscope, use a multimeter to measure this voltage.)*  If the measured voltage at the LM317's input is at or below

$$
11.5\,\mathrm{V} + V_{DO} \approx 11.5\,\mathrm{V} + 2\,\mathrm{V} = 13.5\,\mathrm{V}
$$

where \$V_{DO}\$ is the LM317's ***dropout voltage*** specification (obtained from the LM317's datasheet), then you know the 19 VDC power source cannot deliver enough power (voltage and current) to the load.  The only option at this point is to replace the existing 19 VDC power source with a different power source that can supply enough power (voltage and current) to operate both the LM317 and the load.

*(P.S. Be sure to have a fire extinguisher handy and always wear eye protection if you're going to try charging lithium batteries without a BMS. See also [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/YuKF8XfCVKQ?t=241).)*